# python regexp 3 the same pairs of [0-9A-Fa-f]

Tags: python, regex, hex

I need a regex for some color which can be described like this:

starts with #
then 3 the same pairs of hex characters (0-9, a-f, A-F). aA and Aa are also the same pairs

Now i have #(([0-9A-Fa-f]){2}){3}

How can I make regexp for the SAME pairs of hex characters?

Some examples of the matching strings:
"#FFFFFF",
"#000000",
"#aAAaaA",
"#050505",
"###93#0b0B0b1B34"

Strings like "#000100" shouldn't match

Comment: why this `"###93#0b0B0b1B34"` should be matched?

Comment: it contents #0b0B0b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with a capturing group and a backreference:

```
#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\1{2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvNqAv/1)

**Details**

- `#` - a `#`
- `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` - Group 1: 2 hex chars
- `\1{2}` - 2 consecutive occurrences of the same value as captured in Group 1.

NOTE: the case insensitive flag is required to make the `\1` backreference match Group 1 contents in a case insensitive way. Bear in mind we need to use a raw string literal to define the regex to avoid overescaping the backreferences.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/52hYR1):

```
import re
strs = ["#FFFFFF","#000000","#aAAaaA","#050505","###93#0b0B0b1B34", "#000100"]
for s in strs:
    m = re.search(r'#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\1{2}', s, flags=re.I)
    if m:
        print("{} MATCHED".format(s))
    else:
        print("{} DID NOT MATCH".format(s))
```

Results:

```
#FFFFFF MATCHED
#000000 MATCHED
#aAAaaA MATCHED
#050505 MATCHED
###93#0b0B0b1B34 MATCHED
#000100 DID NOT MATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

With `re.search()` function:

```
import re

s = '#aAAaaA'
match = re.search(r'#([0-9a-z]{2})\1\1', s, re.I)
result = match if not match else match.group()

print(result)
```

---

- `\1` - points to the 1st parenthesized group `(...)`
- `re.I` - *IGNORECASE* regex flag